How to make a gradient move lower in the center and higher on the corners?
I'm trying to create a gradient that rises from both the right and left corners but dips in the center, something like this:

To achieve this effect, I combined two gradients—one positioned at the bottom-left corner and another at the bottom-right corner—so that together, they visually appear as a single gradient that dips in the center. However, I'm encountering two issues that I need help resolving:

The transition in the middle of the screen is too sharp. I've illustrated this in the screenshot below. The "Currently" section shows how it looks now, while the "Expected" section represents the smoother curve I want the gradient to follow.



The second issue is that where the two gradients overlap in the center, they diminish the overall gradient effect.


I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to fix these issues.
Code:
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.drawBehind
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import kotlin.math.PI
import kotlin.math.atan2
import kotlin.math.cos
import kotlin.math.hypot
import kotlin.math.sin

@Composable
fun JustGradient() {
    val gradientColorsList: List<Color> = listOf(
        Color.Transparent,
        Color.Transparent,
        Color.Transparent,
        Color.Transparent,
        Color.Transparent,
        Color.Green.copy(alpha = 0.2f),
        Color.Green.copy(alpha = 0.3f),
        Color.Green.copy(alpha = 0.4f),
        Color.Green.copy(alpha = 0.5f),
        Color.Green.copy(alpha = 0.9f)
    )

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(400.dp)
            .background(Color.Red.copy(alpha = .3f))
            .applyGradient(gradientColorsList)
    )
}

private fun Modifier.applyGradient(gradientColorsList: List<Color>?): Modifier = this
    .let {
        if (gradientColorsList?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
            it.angledGradientBackground(
                colors = gradientColorsList,
                degrees = 45f
            )
        } else {
            it
        }
    }
    .let {
        if (gradientColorsList?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
            it.angledGradientBackground(
                colors = gradientColorsList,
                degrees = 135f
            )
        } else {
            it
        }
    }

private fun Modifier.angledGradientBackground(colors: List<Color>, degrees: Float) = this
    .drawBehind {
        /*
        Have to compute length of gradient vector so that it lies within
        the visible rectangle.
        --------------------------------------------
        | length of gradient ^  /                  |
        |             --->  /  /                   |
        |                  /  / <- rotation angle  |
        |                 /  o --------------------|  y
        |                /  /                      |
        |               /  /                       |
        |              v  /                        |
        --------------------------------------------
                             x

                   diagonal angle = atan2(y, x)
                 (it's hard to draw the diagonal)

        Simply rotating the diagonal around the centre of the rectangle
        will lead to points outside the rectangle area. Further, just
        truncating the coordinate to be at the nearest edge of the
        rectangle to the rotated point will distort the angle.
        Let α be the desired gradient angle (in radians) and γ be the
        angle of the diagonal of the rectangle.
        The correct for the length of the gradient is given by:
        x/|cos(α)|  if -γ <= α <= γ,   or   π - γ <= α <= π + γ
        y/|sin(α)|  if  γ <= α <= π - γ, or π + γ <= α <= 2π - γ
        where γ ∈ (0, π/2) is the angle that the diagonal makes with
        the base of the rectangle.
        */

        val (x, y) = size
        val gamma = atan2(y, x)

        if (gamma == 0f || gamma == (PI / 2).toFloat()) {
            // degenerate rectangle
            return@drawBehind
        }

        val degreesNormalised = (degrees % 360).let { if (it < 0) it + 360 else it }
        val alpha = (degreesNormalised * PI / 180).toFloat()

        val gradientLength: Float = when (alpha) {
            // ray from centre cuts the right edge of the rectangle
            in 0f..gamma, in (2* PI - gamma)..2* PI -> { x / cos(alpha) }
            // ray from centre cuts the top edge of the rectangle
            in gamma..(PI - gamma).toFloat() -> { y / sin(alpha) }
            // ray from centre cuts the left edge of the rectangle
            in (PI - gamma)..(PI + gamma) -> { x / -cos(alpha) }
            // ray from centre cuts the bottom edge of the rectangle
            in (PI + gamma)..(2* PI - gamma) -> { y / -sin(alpha) }
            // default case (which shouldn't really happen)
            else -> hypot(x, y)
        }

        val centerOffsetX = cos(alpha) * gradientLength / 2
        val centerOffsetY = sin(alpha) * gradientLength / 2

        drawRect(
            brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                colors = colors,
                // negative here so that 0 degrees is left -> right
                // and 90 degrees is top -> bottom
                start = Offset(center.x - centerOffsetX, center.y - centerOffsetY),
                end = Offset(center.x + centerOffsetX, center.y + centerOffsetY)
            ),
            size = size
        )
    }


In my interpretation your expected boundary function is a parabola and you are trying to do a image gradient to the function. Realized that you are doing it in Kotlin/Canvas rather than a AGSL/GLSL with a Texture so I'm not sure if you are familiar with https://thebookofshaders.com/ and with a bit of searching able to find: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/mdX3WH which while not a direct answer may provide a possible path.

Instead of 45,45 gradients try 30,30 or 60,60 (whichever produces non-overlapping triangles in ratio 2:1 and then add one vertical gradient. That will get closer to your required shape although the overlaps will still be visible. Maybe add  a blur on top?
